# Deleting row by id not working in Asp.net core web API + Angular 9

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, angular9

I am trying to delete the column by passing id from Angular 9+ to ASP.NET Core Web API, but I am not able to hit in the controller. What mistake I have done here? I am using table data to run SQL queries.

**Controller**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SettlementController : ControllerBase
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    private readonly DatabaseContext _context;

    public SettlementController(IConfiguration configuration, DatabaseContext context)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _context = context;
    }

    // Delete settlement by id
    [Route("DeleteById")]
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public IActionResult DeleteSettlementById([FromBody] SettlementModel model) //sealed class of having Id only
    {
        var tid = model.Id;

        try
        {
            string sConn = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:ServerConnection"];

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sConn))
            {
                List<Object> objList = new List<Object>();

                // This is the stored procedure. I pass in the "Id"
                string query = "ST_PRO_DELETESETTLEMENT"; 

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tid;

                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = con;

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            objList.Add(new
                            {
                                //TID = reader[0].ToString(),
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    con.Close();
                }

                return Ok(objList);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

**settlementService.ts** file:

```
 deleteSettlement(id) {
     console.log(id);
     return this.http.delete(this.BaseURL + 'Settlement/DeleteById/' + id);
 }
```

Typescript file:

```
deleteSettle(tid) {
    console.log(tid);  // getting tid in console

    if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ? TID: '+ tid)) {
        this.settlementService.deleteSettlement(tid).subscribe(
            (data: any) => {
                this.toastr.success("Successfully deleted");
            },
            err => {
               if (err.status == 400)
                  this.toastr.error('Server error or bad request', 'Error');
               else
                  this.toastr.error('Failed to check data', 'Server Error');
            }
      );
   }
}
```

Error:

> DELETE https://localhost:44372/api/Settlement/DeleteById/355 404

Comment: If you have a stored procedure that does the `DELETE` in the database - **why** are you using `ExecuteReader` ?? That makes absolutely no sense - you're not expecting back a result set that needs to be read...... just use `ExecuteNonQuery()`  instead! And also: you should assign the connection to the `SqlCommand` object **before** using `.Open()` on it - preferably in the constructor

Comment: `this.BaseURL` has the same value for other apis being called from angular? Can you call this API from postman?

Comment: In addition to marc_s comment - calling `ExecuteNonQuery` will return the number of rows affected by the SQL Statement so if what you want is confirmation that the row was actually deleted, you can simply check whether ExecuteNonQuery returned a positive value.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya this.BaseURL is also the same value.  PostMan error:  415 Unsupported Media Type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `route` path has been overridden by this attribute `[HttpDelete("{id}")]`

So just remove the Route attribute and add your attribute like this

```
[HttpDelete("DeleteById/{id}")]
```

Next you need to remove the `[FromBody]` attribute in the method parameters and write like this

```
public IActionResult DeleteSettlementById(int id)
```

Hope it helps - Happy coding :)